# Problem loading pages in an iframe in Firefox

Tags: firefox, iframe

I have an aspx page that has an iFrame in it, I set the src attribute of this iFrame in the page load event.

The page that gets loaded into the iFrame has its own references to its own stylesheets and javascript files, but when the page loads, it tries to locate these files with a path from the parent page.

Example structure:

/application/example/parentpage.aspx

/application/iframepages/iframepage.html

/application/iframepages/css/iframepagecss.css

/application/iframepages/scripts/iframepagescript.js

With the iframepage.html containing the following lines:

link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iframepage.css" type="text/css"

script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="scripts/iframepagescript.js"

The problem seems to be when iframepage.html loads in the iframe on parentpage.aspx, it tries to load the css file from the path application/example/css/iframepagecss.css and likewise for the javascript it tries to load it from application/example/scripts/iframepagescript.js.

This only happens in Firefox, it works fine in IE, Chrome and Safari. Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [AJAX and Relative Path Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171074/ajax-and-relative-path-scope) you can try to use the [BASE HREF](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp) tag, or otherwise use absolute paths instead.